# Comparing a word in one list with words in other lists

Tags: python

How could I go about checking to see if a word in one list is equal to a word in another list?
For example, I have three lists:

```
["fish", "boat", "oar"], ["rod", "gunwale", "fish", "net"], ["net", "hook", "weight"]
```

How can I check to see if the words in the first list appear in any of the other lists?  For example, how could I iterate over every word of the other two lists to see if the word "fish" is in them, and the same with "boat" and "oar."

Comment: Do you want to compare one list with the others? Or each one with every other?

Comment: Each one with the others.

Comment: Please provide a optional input and a desired output. Not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: What is the context of this, what do you really want to do? Because sets might be useful here. Or not. Depending on the context.

Comment: What I'm ultimately trying to do is return a count depending on if a word in one list is in none, one, or both of the other lists.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I just combined all your responses to work out what I needed to do! This was very very helpful, you guys rock.

Answer (score 7):

You can just use the `in` operator:

```
l1 = ["fish", "boat", "oar"]
l2 = ["rod", "gunwale", "fish", "net"]
l3 = ["net", "hook", "weight"] 

for w in l1:
  if w in l2:
    print 'found %s in l2!' % w
  if w in l3:
    print 'found %s in l3!' % w
```

If you want to check if it is in ANY of the other two lists, you can just combine them and do the same check inside:

```
if w in l2 + l3:
  print 'found %s in another list!'
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/G4KX)

Comment: A small addition to this answer: The OP wants to check if the elements of the first list appear in *any* of the the other lists, which implies that he/she may not even care whether it's ``l2`` or ``l3``. In that case, even ``if w in l2 + l3:`` would be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks, I'm updating the answer :)

Comment: Why is the output of you code stopping at `found fish in l2!` . This isn't reporting the repeated value `net`

Comment: @everestial007: Because the OP is interested only in the elements of ``l1``, which doesn't contain ``net`` (at least that's what the question suggests).

Comment: oh, ok. I missed that part.

Answer (score 2):

You can use set intersection function, for example:

```
s1 = set(["fish", "boat", "oar"]) 
s2 = set(["rod", "gunwale", "fish", "net"])
s3 = set(["net", "hook", "weight"])
commonS12 = s1 & s2#gives you common elements
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on your latest comment, you seem to wish to count the number of lists which contain the elements of the first lists. Here's a small function that does exactly that:

```py
def count_in_lists(e, lol):
    """
    Count how many of the lists passed in the list of lists 'lol' contain
    the element 'e'.
    """
    count = 0
    for current_list in lol:
        if e in current_list:
            count += 1
    return count
```

Now, similar to casraf's answer, iterate through `l1`, and call the function `count_in_lists()` with the current element of `l1` as the first parameter and a list containing all other lists that you're interested in as the second parameter:

```py
for w in l1:
    print("'{}' is contained in {} other lists".format(
                w, 
                count_in_lists(w, [l2, l3])))
```

This gives you this output:

```
'fish' is contained in 1 other lists
'boat' is contained in 0 other lists
'oar' is contained in 0 other lists
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l1 = ["fish", "boat", "oar"]
l2 = ["rod", "gunwale", "fish", "net"]
l3 = ["net", "hook", "weight"]

print("Intersection between l1 and l2",list(set(l1).intersection(l2)))
print("Intersection between l2 and l3",list(set(l2).intersection(l3)))
print("Intersection between l1 and l3",list(set(l1).intersection(l3)))

print("Intersection between l1 and l2 and l3",list(set(l1).intersection(l2).intersection(l3)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can collect all three lists in one list:

```
lists = [["fish", "boat", "oar"], ["rod", "gunwale", "fish", "net"], ["net", "hook", "weight"]]
```

Then loop through the list of lists, and for each element in the current list check if it is in any of the other lists using the `in` operator:

```
import itertools
for lst in lists:
    # this chains all lists different than the current one into one flat list
    other_lists = list(itertools.chain(*filter(lambda l: l is not lst, lists)))
    for elm in lst:
        if elm in other_lists:
            print '%s found in another list' % elm
```

This is a generic answer, valid for any number of lists, not just three.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using list comprehension.

```
l1 = ["fish", "boat", "oar"]
l2 = ["rod", "gunwale", "fish", "net"]
l3 = ["net", "hook", "weight"] 

print(["{0} is in {1}".format(x, [m for m, li in globals().items() if li is L]) for x in l1 for L in [l2,l3] if x in L][0])
# use globals().iteritems() in python 2
```

Output:

```
"fish is in [l1]"
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data is of different structure as OP suggested.

```
question_data = ques_data = [["fish", "boat", "oar"], ["rod", "gunwale", "fish", "net"], ["net", "hook", "weight"]]
```

We might need to take a different approach. Also, it's important to do this in a for loop so it can search no matter how long the list is:

```
l1_values = ques_data[0]
remaining_list = ques_data[1::]

print(l1_values) # gives
['fish', 'boat', 'oar']

print(remaining_list) # gives
[['rod', 'gunwale', 'fish', 'net'], ['net', 'hook', 'weight']]

count = 1
for x in l1_values:
    for lists in remaining_list:
        count =+ 2
        if x in lists:
        print(x + ' is in list #' + str(count))

# gives the answer as:
fish is in list #2

        print(x + ' is in list ' + str(lists))

# gives the answer as:
fish is in list ['rod', 'gunwale', 'fish', 'net']
```